# Скрипт- вычисление ширины элемента

Tags: jquery

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы в скрипте для вычисления ширины элемента получалось численное значение, а не строка ?

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        var width = $('.controls').css('width')+$('.controls').css('padding-left')+$('.controls').css('padding-right');
        alert (width);
            });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конкретно для вашей задачи я бы воспользовался функцией `$.outerWidth`. Она учитывает величину паддингов и бордеров в отличии от `$.width`

[outerWidth](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/)

```
$('.controls').outerWidth()
$('.controls').outerWidth(true) // учитывая margin
```

Comment: спасибо, мне это свойство раньше не попадалось.

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь функцией [parseInt()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp)

Comment: спасибо за подсказку!)